# How to prevent data inconsistencies with chat application in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

I have a chat application using node.js and socket.io that stores user information in Redis and MongoDB. When a user first connects to the socket server, a user ID is generated for them, and this id (along with their username) is stored on the socket object. The full user information (including avatar picture, email, etc) is stored in MongoDB, and a portion of that is also cached in Redis. When a client disconnects from the socket server, the event is handled by the following event handler:

```
const handleDisconnect = async () => {
  const {userId, username} = socket;
  if (userId && username) {
    try {
      delete socket.userId;
      delete socket.username;

      await redisClient.del(`user:${userId}`);

      await User.findByIdAndDelete(userId);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

Now, since the commands which delete the user from Redis and Mongo are async, there is at least in theory the possibility that they could throw. For example, if the command to delete from Redis throws, then the one below that won't run and the user won't be deleted from MongoDB.

The same thing could happen even when adding the user to these databases in the first place, since database commands can always theoretically fail to execute and leave things in an inconsistent state.

Is there a standard way to handle these situations?

Should I implement better exception handling so that I will catch every possible error, and keep retrying the database commands until they succeed?

Or should I implement some sort of garbage collection that periodically goes through the databases and cleans up documents which weren't successfully deleted?

Comment: Catch them separately, so you can retry and/or continue with the other operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I implement better exception handling so that I will catch every possible error

If each of the commands in your try-catch block can fail, and you generally want to execute all of them, I would certainly add a try-catch block around *each* command rather all of them together.

One approach you may consider is to store a single value in redis that indicates whether the rest of the data is (fully) there, for example userid/username. When writing data into redis, set this value last. When cleaning up, delete it first. When reading from redis, check if this value is present, then continue to read other data. This way you can have partial data in redis but your application will not try to work with it.

With any cache there is a possibility of the cache being out of date. You may also consider which operations *require* up to date data (such as authentication) and which don't (such as showing # of new messages). The latter can often tolerate some staleness. The exact degree depends on the application.